# Fcm's MulticastMessage has a limit of 500. What should I do if I want to send more than 500 at once?

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the server receives an List accountId, it creates and transmits a corresponding tokenList,
but Fcm's MulticastMessage has a limit of 500.
What should I do if I want to send more than 500 at once?

FcmController.java

```
    List<String> registrationTokens = fcmService.getTokenList(accountIdList);

    MulticastMessage message = MulticastMessage.builder()
            .putData("title", title)
            .putData("content", msg)
            .addAllTokens(registrationTokens)
            .build();

    BatchResponse response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticast(message);
```

FcmService.java

```
 public List<String> getTokenList(List<Long> accountIdList) {
        List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long accountId:accountIdList) {
            String token = fcmRepository.findById(accountId).get().getToken();
            tokenList.add(token);
        }
        return tokenList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Topics**
   It is possible to send a message to almost [unlimited number of
   devices subscribed to a
   topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging).
2. **Multicast batches**
   Group multicast messages into batches, sending one after another, maximum 500 messages each.